# Why did removing a feature only removed part of the functionality (not flags?)

Tags: 7, features, flags

I just removed a Feature module (a module created by [Features](https://drupal.org/project/features)) from my site and I discovered that some of the functionality that the module added is still present on the site.  Specifically, two flags are still available on their designated content type.  Here is what I did:

- I created a feature module which contained two flags, two menu items and a view.
- I uploaded the feature module to my test site
- I activated it via check-box at Home › Administration › Structure > Features
- I verified that all functionality was added
- I deactivated it via check-box at Home › Administration › Structure > Features
- I attempted to verify that the functionality was removed.
- I discovered that the two flags still existed on their designated content type.

Did I miss a step or are flags not removed when a feature is disabled?

Comment: The Features module actually creates other modules.  You then install these new modules on other sites to migrate functionality.

Comment: makes more sense now with the edit :)  Assuming you don't have anything else relying on Features, have you tried deactivating Features itself?